# How to use an authenticated user in a Symfony2 functional test?

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

I use the `FacebookBundle` to authenticate users in my Symfony2 application. However, I would like to create functional tests with phpunit which uses an authenticated user.

Moreover, I don't want to use a facebook user for this, but harcoded one.

Does anybody know how to implement this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's actually quite simple.

1. Setup `security.yml` for test environment (it's a snippet from Symfony 2.0-RC3)

   ```
   security:
       encoders:
           Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

       providers:
           in_memory:
               users:
                   user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                   admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

       firewalls:
            secured-area:
                pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
                http_basic:
                    realm: "Secured Demo Area"
   ```
2. As you can see there is HTTP Authentication defined. So now, all you have to do is to setup a client in functional test:

   ```
   $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
       'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'user',
       'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'userpass',
   ));
   ```

---

This link might be useful: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I want this user to have a lot of other property which are used in my application. For instance, they have a $facebookId property. How can I use hardcoded users with custom properties ?

Comment: How do you specify a different security config for the test environment? I'd love to be able to change my cusom wsse proviver to basic in memory.

Comment: @whistlergreg I believe all you have to do is to override `security` definition in `config_test.yml/.xml`.

Comment: tried that, i get `You are not allowed to define new elements for path "security.providers". Please define all elements for this path in one config file.`

Comment: @whistlergreg Then move import of `security.yml` from `config.yml` to `config_prod/dev.yml`, create `security_test.yml` and import it in `config_test.yml`. You might also need to remove a dependency for `config_dev.yml` from `config_test.yml`.