# Symfony functional tests: bypass security

Tags: php, symfony

In our project smartcard auth is used, where card contains user certificete.
I want to test my controoller, but it has some `if (!$this->security->isGranted(...)) throw new AccessDeniedException();` lines.

How can I bypass all security verifications in functional tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use an authenticated user in a Symfony2 functional test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535873/how-to-use-an-authenticated-user-in-a-symfony2-functional-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer: [How to use an authenticated user in a Symfony2 functional test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535873/how-to-use-an-authenticated-user-in-a-symfony2-functional-test)

Different `security` section in configuration should be used.