# Symfony 3 functional test: authenticate user of own User class

Tags: testing, phpunit, symfony

I'd like to run functional tests on a section of my website which requires authentication. I found a solution for Symfony 2.x [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538211/symfony-2-functional-test-authenticate-user-of-own-user-class#answer-16543995). However, this does not work for Symfony3 as this line is now deprecated:

```
self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

My question is, how do I go around this and make it work with Symfony3? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 3, the `SecurityContext` was split into the `TokenStorage` and the `AuthorizationChecker`. Thus, you need to use the `security.token_storage` service:

```
self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
```

However, a simpler approach would be to switch to HTTP Basic auth in your tests and configure the logged in user as described in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html.